# Why is 'while' sometimes a synonym of 'whereas', and sometimes of 'although'?

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, subordinate-clauses

> The north of the country is mountainous while the south is flat.

= The  north of the country is mountainous whereas (*although* would be incorrect) the south is flat.

> The north of the country while it is mountainous is more densely populated than the south, which is flat.

= The north of the country although (*whereas* would be incorrect) it is mountainous is more densely populated than the south, which is flat.

Why is it impossible to use 'although' in the first sentence, and 'whereas' in the second, where 'while' can be used in both?

Comment: Why can't you use *although* in the first sentence?

Comment: Agreed. _Although_ is perfectly grammatical, and so are _but, and, though,_ and _however_. So you're starting off with the wrong rules; maybe you need to rethink the question?

Comment: @PeterShor: because there is no ground for deducing that the south of the country is flat from the fact that the north is mountainous, whereas what normally happens in most countries in the world is that the areas that are mountainous are less populated than the ones that are flat (provided they are not deserts!), so, from the fact that the north of the country is mountainous, you have grounds for deducing that is must be or is very likely to be less densely populated.

Comment: @PeterShor: 'While-whereas' is used when there is no idea of result, of a cause and effect relationship, and 'while-although' is used when there is. 'While', 'one thing at the same time as another' just states a co-occurrence which can be owed to a cause and effect relationship or not, which 'whereas' and 'although' detail.

Comment: @user58319 In the absence of additional context, neither *although* nor *while* suggests causality or dependency on its own, only contradistinction (like those John Lawler suggested, and others like *yet*). In context it can have that meaning, but otherwise, I would need a different conjunction that more strongly expresses a contrast that is unexpected, like *even though* or *despite that*.

Comment: @choster: as I said in my comment to the second answer, 'while' can mean 'two things at the same time, without the idea that those things are in contrast', it can mean 'two contrasting things at the same time, without the idea that there should normally have been a cause and effect relationship at work' and it can mean 'a(n ineffectual) cause and not the expected effect, or the opposite of the expected effect'. That is why replacing a word with a synonym can be so tricky. 'While' is very polysemic and you must know which of its meanings you are dealing with in order to replace it correctly.

Comment: @PeterShor & John Lawler: do you want me to change the first sentence to the one provided in the second answer, "Nepal is mountainous while/whereas Holland is flat."? (Don't you agree that here, replacing 'while' with 'although' would be incorrect?)

Comment: I agree that *although* would be incorrect in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Because while is serving two different functions in both sentences, ie. Although or whereas. While can also mean 'occurring at the same time', like in the sentence "while my parents were cooking, I was watching TV". You can't substitute 'although' or 'whereas' for 'while' there either without changing the tone of the sentence. Sometimes words just have multiple meanings.

Comment: and the reason you cannot replace 'while' with either 'although' or 'whereas' in your sentence is that there is no contrast, no opposition between 'cook' and 'watch TV' whereas there is between 'mountainous areas' and 'flat areas', between 'more densely populated' and 'less densely populated'. 'While' can carry the idea of time only, time and contrast only, or time, contrast, and (thwarted) causality

Answer (score 1):

*Although* still works OK in the first sentence; it's not impossible.  Your example just happens to be capable of bearing the meaning "in spite of the fact that . . ".    You could even use "but" in that particular sentence.

"Although" fails as a subordinating conjunction when there is no reasonable expectation of one thing from the other.  You wouldn't say "Nepal has mountains although Holland is flat", except in really special situations.  But comparing two areas of the same country is more likely.

Much less happy with *is mountains* and *is plains*.  You need adjectives there, like "mountainous" and "flat", not nouns, especially plural nouns.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, although, I think 'is (made of/consists in) mountains/plains' can easily be understood and is not poor usage.

Comment: Like the contrastive 'while', 'but' can carry the idea of cause and effect or not, there is a 'but-although-even though' and a 'but-whereas-instead'